# st_within function of GeoSPARQL on Virtuoso

Tags: virtuoso, geosparql

I installed [Virtuoso Open Source Edition 07.20.3217](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews).

But GeoSPARQL does not work as I expected.

I inserted 10 triples --

```
prefix   owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix  rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix   geo:  <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
prefix    ex:  <http://www.example.org/POI#>
prefix    sf:  <http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#>
prefix   rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

ex:WashingtonMonument 
   rdf:type          ex:Monument  
   rdfs:label        "Washington Monument"  ;
   geo:hasGeometry   ex:WMPoint  .

ex:WMPoint 
   rdf:type          sf:Point  ;
   geo:asWKT         "POINT(-77.03524 38.889468)"^^geo:wktLiteral  .

ex:NationalMall 
   a                 ex:Park  ;
   rdfs:label        "National Mall"  ;
   geo:hasGeometry   ex:NMPoly  .

ex:NMPoly 
   a                 sf:Polygon  ;
   geo:asWKT         "POLYGON((-77.050125 38.892086, -77.039482 38.892036, -77.039482 38.895393, -77.033669 38.895508, -77.033585 38.892052, -77.031906 38.892086, -77.031883 38.887474, -77.050232 38.887142, -77.050125 38.892086 ))"^^geo:wktLiteral  .
```

Then I tried this GeoSPARQL query --

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?m  geo:hasGeometry  ?mgeo .
  ?p  geo:hasGeometry  ?pgeo .
  FILTER (bif:st_within(?mgeo, ?pgeo))
}
```

But there is no result.

What did I do wrong?

Thank you for any response.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections in this post, TallTed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to specify that you're looking for Monuments within Parks.  Also, I don't think you want a wildcard result, but only the list of such Monuments and Parks.

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>

SELECT ?monument  
       ?park
WHERE
  {
    ?monument                a  ex:Monument ;
               geo:hasGeometry  ?mgeo       .

    ?park                    a  ex:Park     ;
               geo:hasGeometry  ?pgeo       .

    FILTER (bif:st_within(?mgeo, ?pgeo))

  }
```

[Live examples](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20%20%20geo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Font%2Fgeosparql%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20lgdo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20wgs%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fmonument%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fmlabel%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fmgeo%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpark%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplabel%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpgeo%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmonument%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%20lgdo%3AMonument%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%3Fmlabel%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wgs%3Ageometry%20%20%3Fmgeo%20%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fpark%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%20lgdo%3APark%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%3Fplabel%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wgs%3Ageometry%20%20%3Fpgeo%20%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28bif%3Ast_within%28%3Fmgeo%2C%20%3Fpgeo%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) are often more useful than hypotheticals, so here's [an adjusted query](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20%20geo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Font%2Fgeosparql%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20lgdo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20wgs%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fmonument%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fmlabel%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fmgeo%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpark%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplabel%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpgeo%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmonument%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%20lgdo%3AMonument%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%3Fmlabel%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wgs%3Ageometry%20%20%3Fmgeo%20%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fpark%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%20lgdo%3APark%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%3Fplabel%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wgs%3Ageometry%20%20%3Fpgeo%20%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28bif%3Ast_within%28%3Fmgeo%2C%20%3Fpgeo%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) that does produce results, though there seems to be an issue with Monument vs Park designation, and both have `POINT` geometry (i.e., no `POLYGON` data) --

```
PREFIX   geo:  <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX  lgdo:  <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/>
PREFIX   wgs:  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT  ?monument  ?mlabel  ?mgeo 
        ?park      ?plabel  ?pgeo
WHERE
  {
    ?monument             a  lgdo:Monument   ;
                 rdfs:label  ?mlabel  ;
               wgs:geometry  ?mgeo  .

    ?park                 a  lgdo:Park  ;
                 rdfs:label  ?plabel  ;
               wgs:geometry  ?pgeo  .

    FILTER (bif:st_within(?mgeo, ?pgeo))
  }
```

I do not have time to find a live dataset that includes `POLYGON` geometry for Parks, and accurately places Monument `POINTs` within such Park `POLYGONs`, so I cannot dig much further ... but if you can make your instance public, or point to a live public instance that holds such data, we can go further.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As your comment, I just want to get Monuments within Parks. But it is not type and wildcard problem. Your GeoSPARQL does not work either.

Comment: I've updated with a live query, but against imperfect data, so with imperfect results...

Comment: Thank you for your guide. I tested some example in "OGC GeoSPARQL - A Geographic Query Language for RDF Data," and it works fine. In the document, they use functions defined opengis.net like geof:sfWithin. Does not Virtuoso support these functions?

Comment: The GeoSPARQL functions in Virtuoso are currently addressable only through the `bif:` pattern, but they will be aliased to the standardized naming in a future Release.  I do not have an ETA for this. To raise priority and keep abreast of updates for the Open Source Edition, best to write to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/) and/or [log an Issue](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/), or, if using Commercial Edition, open a [Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Comment: The "Live example" above returns only results where ?monument=?park, that's not what is wanted

Comment: @VladimirAlexiev Do you have an example of `?monument` and `?park` where relevant descriptions of both are present in this dataset, the `?monument` is found within the `?park`, and the pair isn't found by this query?

Comment: @VladimirAlexiev Note that as I said in my answer, the data in my example instance describes both monuments and parks only with `POINT` for `wgs:geometry` -- there are no `POLYGON` values. A dataset that describes monuments with `POINT` and parks with `POLYGON` would be helpful.

Comment: @VladimirAlexiev Please note that the queries and examples in my answer are being run against the public DBpedia instance, not the sample data from the question. I will try to find time to conduct more experiments in a local instance, including loading and querying against the OP's sample data.